# Is this integral operator about Stokes' Flow compact?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Consider the following integral operator $\mathcal{A}$ on [EDITED: continuous vector function $f=(f_i):\partial S\to{\mathbb R}^3$]:
$$
({\mathcal A}f)_j(x_0):=\int_{\partial S}\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i(x)G_{ij}(x,x_0)dS(x),\quad j = 1,2,3,\quad x_0\in \partial S,
$$
where 
$$
G_{ij}(x,x_0)=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{r}+\frac{\hat{x}_i\hat{x}_j}{r^3},\quad\hat{x}=x-x_0, \quad r = |\hat{x}|,
$$
$S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is closed, bounded, simply connected, $\partial S$ is Lyapunov.

This operator is from the representation of the solution of Stokes flow by boundary integral from *Boundary Integral and Singularity Methods for Linearized Viscous Flow* by C. Pozrikidis. The author has slightly mentioned the compactness of this linear operator without giving a proof. I'm interested in *how* to prove it. I have not seen this integral operator before. Those in the book I learned functional analysis from are all of 1 dimension. Thus the basic techniques seem not helpful here.

**Questions:**

> - How should I deal with the compactness of [EDITED: $\mathcal A:C(\partial S\to{\mathbb R}^3)\to C(\partial S\to{\mathbb R}^3)$]?
> - Can anybody come up with a reference about this kind of high-dimension integral operators?

[**Added**]Some thoughts:
It may be easier to investigate the compactness of the following operator:
$$
({\mathcal A_{ij}}g)(x_0):=\int_{\partial S}g(x)G_{ij}(x,x_0)dS(x),
$$
where $g\in C(\partial S\to{\mathbb R})$. Is the compactness of ${\mathcal A}_{ij}$ related to ${\mathcal A}$?

Comment: What sould the domain and range spaces be?

Comment: @TaQ: Good comment! I've edited my question. 

Comment: Obviously, by Ascoli's theorem, compactness of the (original) operator in question follows if one can prove that for every $\varepsilon\in{\mathbb R}^+$ there is $\delta\in{\mathbb R}^+$ such that $\int_{\partial S}|G_{ij}(x,x_1)-G_{ij}(x,x_0)|dS(x) < \varepsilon$ whenever $x_0,x_1\in\partial S$ with $|x_1-x_0| < \delta$. (I do not know what does it mean that the boundary is Lyapunov.)